# React: Conditionally show and hide CSS selector

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to apply the 'side-nav--selected' style if location = 'test'

```
const location = 'test';
...
<div className='side-nav--item {if location === 'test' && side-nav--selected'}>Test</div>
<div className='side-nav--item {if location === 'left' && side-nav--selected'}>Left</div>
```

The error I get is `Parsing error: Identifier expected`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div className={`side-nav--item ${second === 'test' && 'side-nav--selected'}`}>...</div>
<div className={`side-nav--item ${second === 'left' && 'side-nav--selected'}`}>...</div>
```

using ternary operator

```
<div className={`side-nav--item ${second === 'test' ? 'side-nav--selected' : '' }`}>...</div>
<div className={`side-nav--item ${second === 'left' ? 'side-nav--selected' : '' }`}>...</div>
```

Comment: Using ternary operator would be better. If the condition `second === 'test'` evaluate to `false` then  `false` as string would be appended to the className.